# Incorrect Client IP in PHP

Tags: php, ip

I am getting a weird result for the client IP in PHP in some cases.

Result in Most Cases (Expected Result) :

```
192.123.132.123
```

Erroneous Result Type 1:

```
for="192.123.132.123"
```

Erroneous Result Type 2:

```
for="192.123.132.123:1232"
```

Code for getting the IP:

```
<?php

function getIP(){
$ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '-';
$proxy = false;
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']) || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $proxy = true;
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'])) {
    $aProxyHosts = array('proxy','cache','inktomi');
    foreach ($aProxyHosts as $proxyName) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], $proxyName) !== false) {
        $proxy = true;
        break;
    }
    }
}
// Has the viewer come via an HTTP proxy?
if ($proxy) {
// Try to find the "real" IP address the viewer has come from
$aHeaders = array('HTTP_FORWARDED','HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_X_FORWARDED','HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
foreach ($aHeaders as $header) {
    if (!empty($_SERVER[$header])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER[$header];
        break;
    }
}
}
if (!empty($ip)) {
// The "remote IP" may be a list, ensure that
// only the last item is used in that case
$ip = explode(',', $ip);
$ip = trim($ip[count($ip) - 1]);
}
return $ip;
}

?>
```

I know that I can clean the result to get the correct value (IP) but I am puzzled at why is this happening in the first place.

*PS: 192.123.132.123 is an arbitrary IP used to explain the issue.*

Answer (score 1):

You're reading arbitrary HTTP headers... not all of them contain purely the IP, some are in the form of `for=...` and some include the port as well.

1. Using any HTTP header instead `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` means you're allowing anyone to mask/fake their IP address by simply sending an HTTP header. You should be perfectly aware of where such headers may be set, which usually means you *know* they're set by a proxy you control. In this case you obviously don't know where those headers are coming from, so you should not use them.
2. If you decide to use an HTTP header, you should know which one exactly you want to read and what format it's in. If its format is `for=...`, then parse that format correctly.

Comment: I am reading headers other that the standard `REMOTE_ADDR` because users might be behind a proxy or be routed through some other link by the ISP. Also, I am reading the `REMOTE_ADDR` first, and only incase it is not available or the user has arrived through proxy, then I am reading the other headers.

Comment: Yes, still, the only *confirmed* address you'll ever get is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. That's the confirmed TCP/IP three-way handshake IP. Anything else is just arbitrary stuff. And what good does it really do you to get a private `192.` address? Virtually everyone has a `192.` address, there are billions of them. That doesn't identify anyone uniquely at all.

Comment: *PS: 192.123.132.123 is an arbitrary IP used to explain the issue.*

Comment: I know. Still, "behind proxy" addresses are typically 192. or 10. addresses, and those are mostly useless for the general internet population. And again, you're allowing anyone to "spoof" their IP trivially by paying attention to those headers. If you're in a more narrowly defined intranet situation, there may be a use for those, but in that case you should also specifically know what headers to look for and what format they're in.